# Derivation of Black-Scholes for a derivative on a stock that pays continuous dividends, and the derivative pays continuous cashflows

Tags: black-scholes

I need help with the derivation of Black-Scholes PDE. The condition is that the derivative is written on a stock that pays dividends continuously (dividend yield D). Additionally, the derivative pays cashflow $C(s,t)$ continuously. I know that the PDE will come out as follows:

$$\frac{}{} +\frac{1}{2}^2^2 \frac{^2 }{S^2} + ( − )
\frac{}{} −  = −(, )$$

But please help me with the actual derivation, and then solving this PDE.

Suppose that the asset price evolves according to the SDE
$$ = ( − ) + $$

In addition,  pays a continuous dividend stream equal to  during the infinitesimal time
interval , where the dividend yield  is a constant.
Suppose a European style derivative security is written on this asset with the properties that at
expiry the holder receives the asset price and prior to expiry the derivative pays a continuous
cash flow (, ) during the infinitesimal time interval .

**I have to show that the above PDE is true given the information above, and then solve the PDE.**

Comment: Is the cashflow conditional or anything? Or is just like a certain interest paid continuously until expiry? Stated otherwise, what is the functional form of $C(S,t)$?

Comment: You can solve the PDE easily using the Feynman-Kac formula by computing a conditional expectation. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula   The derivation of the PDE will be similar to the BS delta hedge argument.